# WebSocket and browsers support

Tags: javascript, web, websocket, client-server, chat

I'm considering using WebSocket in order to implement a basic 1-1 chat application.

According to this website: http://caniuse.com/websockets
IE6-IE9 doesn't support WebSocket.

I think in 2014 it's legitimate not to support IE6/7, but still many users use IE8/9.

So I think choosing WebSocket isn't good for me.

What do you think about my case? Should I use WebSocket? and what's the best alternative?

Thanks.

**Update:**
I'm using Play! framework

Comment: You can implement chat using [Server-Sent Events](http://caniuse.com/eventsource), which, despite having zero native support as far as IE goes, can be shimmed with AJAX.

Comment: most decent socket packages like socket.io, pubnub, etc provide fallback old-school fallback server-push technologies like long-poll, SSE, COMET, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets work great when they are supported by the browser and by all the plumbing between your service and client. In addition to the browser issues, many proxies and load balancers don't support websockets either.

I would suggest using websockets but also implementing some sort of fallback to long-polling or server-sent events if that doesn't work.

Since you didn't mention server types or languages, I'm unable to provide any recommendations.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Play! framework. Can you give me some recommendations please?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Play! but I have used Atmosphere and found it to work well. According to the Atmosphere documentation, they support Play! https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-play. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Flash based WebSocket polyfill that works on older IEs: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

Then there is Google Chrome Frame for IE.

To mitigate problems with intermediaries not aware of WebSocket, use TLS (secure WebSocket). That will make it work in nearly all situations (exception being MITM / TLS intercepting proxies).

Comment: Thanks. What's the deal with Google Chrome Frame for IE?

Comment: Chrome Frame will essentially render a HTML page in IE window using Chrome under the hood _if_ the HTML page includes a certain directive to enable that. When the page doesn't contain the hint, IE renders the page as normally.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't order my users to use this extension :)

Comment: Sure. It can help with closed user groups. Most people however do have Flash on IE also. Using the Flash polyfill allows you to avoid HTTP long-poll based fallbacks.